# How do I install bitlbee on my pi?

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-stretch

```
❯ sudo apt-get install bitlbee                                                                                                                                                                                                          253msReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bitlbee : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.3.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've looked around and can't find libgnutls, I even tried just [compiling it myself](https://github.com/bitlbee/bitlbee) but it can't seem to find any ssl libraries - gnutls and openssl have no dev packages.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just looked on a fresh flashed `Raspbian Stretch Light 2018-04-18` image and doing this:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt list bitlbee*
Listing... Done
bitlbee/stable 3.5.1-1 armhf
bitlbee-common/stable 3.5.1-1 all
bitlbee-dev/stable 3.5.1-1 all
bitlbee-libpurple/stable 3.5.1-1 armhf
bitlbee-plugin-otr/stable 3.5.1-1 armhf
```

For dev files for gnutls and openssl I find:

```
rpi ~$ apt list *gnutls*-dev
Listing... Done
libcurl4-gnutls-dev/stable 7.52.1-5+deb9u6 armhf
libghc-gnutls-dev/stable 0.2-4 armhf
libgnutls28-dev/stable 3.5.8-5+deb9u3 armhf
libneon27-gnutls-dev/stable 0.30.2-2 armhf

rpi ~$ apt list *openssl*-dev
Listing... Done
libcurl4-openssl-dev/stable 7.52.1-5+deb9u6 armhf
libghc-hsopenssl-dev/stable 0.11.3.2-3 armhf
libghc-hsopenssl-x509-system-dev/stable 0.1.0.3-2 armhf
libghc-openssl-streams-dev/stable 1.2.1.0-4 armhf
libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-dev/stable 3.8-1 armhf
libglobus-openssl-module-dev/stable 4.8-1 armhf
lua-openssl-dev/stable 20161208-1 armhf
```

Installing bitlbee works without any problems:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install bitlbee
```

I suggest you should do the same: flash a new image and install `bitlbee`.

Comment: so libgnutls28-dev showed up, but bitlbee couldn't be installed from apt, still. After installing libgnutls28-dev and libgcrypt11-dev and libgcrypt20-dev I was able to ./configure, make and make install